# OAuth Facebook Authorisation via Facebook App instead of Web Browser

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, oauth

I'm intending to use OAuth for Facebook Authorisation in my iOS(Swift) Application. But knowing that most of the people are logged in to Facebook iOS App instead of Safari(or web browser), I want the Native App Authorisation page to show up instead of the same page on a Browser, where user may need to sign in again.

My URL is: http://zafaafh-dev.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook/

I have tried via URL Schemes too.

FB URL Scheme: fb://zafaafh-dev.azurewebsites.net/login/facebook/

It just opens FB App but Not the required Authorisation page.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your app to the Facebook app dashboard. Then follow this guide for adding Facebook authentication to your app for [Swift](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift). Update your Info.plist and AppDelegate.swift according to the docs.
AppDelegate.swift should look like something like this:

**Swift 3.0**

```
import UIKit
import FacebookCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

        AppEventsLogger.activate(application)
   }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    }

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
        application,
        open: url as URL!,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't find anything OAuth in the link you shared. I know how to add a FB Login Button and make it open the Application. I need to open the OAuth Facebook Authorisation to go through the App not Safari.